# Windows.h - GUI as CMD

Tags: c++

I'm a student and I'm looking for help, so I can deal with projects to pass.
I do not speak fluent english as I'm not native, but believe me I do try my best.

My professor wants me to make "text editor" in C++ using just a Windows.h, that is in console. First, easiest case is to get max of 6 letters and just print them out on the screen. Second, semi-case is to get max of 6 letters but each after pressing an Enter button. Third - the hardest is to get max of 6 letters but if there will be more letters, text should be overwritten.

EXAMPLE: E X A M P L E S -> E S A M P L E S

So I need some clues or ideas in the first place. In the second place I need some help understanding Windows.h. I read a lot of docummentation, but let's say WriteConsole function is some black magic to me here:

lpNumberOfCharsWritten [out]
A pointer to a variable that receives the number of characters actually written.

I can't understand that at all. I just simply need it to Write chosen keys to buffer, and then print it out.
I'm stuck.

Thank you for every answer.
// EDIT

With both ur answers I finally moved on, so thank you for your time.

But I have problem now to print specific key to console.

**

```
while (counter++ <= 100)
{
    // Wait for the events. 

    for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
    {
        switch (irInBuf[i].EventType)
        {
        case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input 
            ++dwWriteCoord.X;
            KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent);

            WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdout,
                    irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar, // this line is wrong
                    1,
                    dwWriteCoord,
                    &cNumRead);
            break;      

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**
I proceed with docummentation and I don't know how to print specific key.

At this moment I left KeyEventProc empty.

So I simply want to press f and print 'f' to the screen, then press o and print 'o' to the screen.

Comment: Sounds like you need to grab a copy of the ancient [*Programming Windows* book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) by Charles Petzold that covers how to write applications using the bare Windows API. Everything else published after that talks about C++ approaches using various Windows C++ libraries, not `windows.h`.

Comment: Wow, that's 20 years old now. But that book itself won't help. The problem here is a matter of thinking logically. Petzold assumes you can program, in particularly in C, but that you're not familiar with Windows. This is far more fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

Let's copy the documentation for reference

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteConsole(
  _In_             HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
  _In_       const VOID    *lpBuffer,
  _In_             DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToWrite,
  _Out_            LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten,
  _Reserved_       LPVOID  lpReserved
);
```

> lpNumberOfCharsWritten [out] A pointer to a variable that receives the
>   number of characters actually written.

So we know that the 4th argument has to be a pointer to a variable. What type of variable? Well, the pointer is a `LPDWORD`. In Microsoft-speak, an `LP-X` is a pointer to X, so `LPDWORD` is `DWORD*`. And `DWORD` is some unspecified 32 bits type. Could be `std::unit32_t`, could be `unsigned long`. You shouldn't need to care.

Either way, you should know C++ well enough to know that `&` is the address operator, so `&variable` is a pointer to `variable`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will write a string in reverse. So it is an example of the WriteConsoleOutputCharacter function. It gets the current cursor position then advances the X value by the length of the string. Then it writes each character out, beginning with the first character and decrementing the cursor position for each character.

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    wchar_t s[] = L"reverse";
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO ConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
    COORD dwWriteCoord;
    DWORD NumberOfCharsWritten;

    std::wcout << s << '\n';

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &ConsoleScreenBufferInfo);
    dwWriteCoord = ConsoleScreenBufferInfo.dwCursorPosition;
    dwWriteCoord.X += wcslen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(s); ++i) {
        --dwWriteCoord.X;
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, s+i, 1, dwWriteCoord, &NumberOfCharsWritten);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The name WriteConsoleOutputCharacter seems confusing. It writes character**s** (plural, therefore a string), not a character.